# Using multiple else if statements

Tags: vbscript

I was trying to make a calculator in VBScript to test my skill, but came across an error. My program uses multiple else if statement to test what the user has input.

Here is my code below:

```
Dim head
Dim msg1, msgErr, msgAns
Dim input1, num1, num2
Dim ans

head = "Calculator"

msg1 = msgBox("Ruan's Vbscript calculator",0,head)
input1 = inputBox("How do you want to calculate? You can type (+ - * /)",head)

num1 = inputBox("Enter your first number",head)
num2 = inputBox("Enter your second number",head)

if (input1 = vbcancel) then
    wscript.quit()
else if (input1 = "+") then
    ans = num1 + num2
else if (input1 = "-") then
    ans = num1 - num2
else if (input1 = "*") then
    ans = num1 * num2
else if (input1 = "/") then
    ans = num1 / num2
else
    msgErr = msgBox("Make sure you type '+' or '-' or '*' or '/' with no extra letter or spaces","Error")
end if

msgAns = msgBox "Your answere is: " + head
```

When I run the program, the error says: "Expected end of statement". I don't see the problem here, as I have `end if` after all those `else if` statements.

Comment: I believe the correct syntax in VBScript is `ElseIf`

http://www.w3schools.com/vbscript/vbscript_conditionals.asp

Comment: `input1 = vbcancel` does not work as some may think.

Comment: Any of the upvoters willing to explain why a calculator that claims that 5+7 is 57 deserves points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the space between `else` and `if` and make it `elseif`. Like this:

```
if (input1 = vbcancel) then
    wscript.quit()
elseif (input1 = "+") then
    ans = num1 + num2
elseif (input1 = "-") then
    ans = num1 - num2
elseif (input1 = "*") then
    ans = num1 * num2
elseif (input1 = "/") then
    ans = num1 / num2
else
    msgErr = msgBox("Make sure you type '+' or '-' or '*' or '/' with no extra letter or spaces","Error")
end if
```

With the additional space between `else` and `if` you start a new `if` statement nested in the `else` branch rather than continuing the first `if` statement. The nested `if` statements require `end if`s of their own, which is why you're getting the error.

Comment: `input1 = vbcancel` does not work as some may think.

Answer (score 2):

Minimal improvements to make it work:

```
Option Explicit

Dim head
Dim msg1, msgErr, msgAns
Dim input1, num1, num2
Dim ans

head = "Calculator"
msgBox "Ruan's Vbscript calculator", 0, head
input1 = inputBox("How do you want to calculate? You can type (+ - * /)",head)
If Not IsEmpty(input1) Then
   num1 = CDbl(inputBox("Enter your first number",head))
   num2 = CDbl(inputBox("Enter your second number",head))
   if     input1 = "+" then
      ans = num1 + num2
   elseif input1 = "-" then
      ans = num1 - num2
   elseif input1 = "*" then
      ans = num1 * num2
   elseif input1 = "/" then
      ans = num1 / num2
   elseif input1 = "\" then
      ans = num1 \ num2
   else
      msgErr = msgBox("Make sure you type '+' or '-' or '*' or '/' with no extra letter or spaces","Error")
   end if
   msgBox "Your answere is: " & ans
else
   msgBox "Aborted"
end if
```

Type and range checks for the operants left as execise.

Answer (score 0):

A `Select Case` is usually a simpler/clearer construction for selecting operations based on a single variables value

```
Select Case input1
    Case vbCancel
        wscript.quit()
    Case "+"
        ans = num1 + num2
    Case "-"
        ans = num1 - num2
    Case "*"
        ans = num1 * num2
    Case "/", "\" '//multiples
        ans = num1 / num2
    Case Else
        msgBox "Make sure you type '+' or '-' or '*' or '/' with no extra letter or spaces", , "Error"
End Select
```

Comment: Please reconsider `Case "/", "\" '//multiples` (misleading comment, real vs integer div).

Comment: `input1 = vbcancel` does not work as some may think.